# Variable not defined (Python)

Tags: python

```
FlightType=input("Which flight would you like to fly? Type '2 Seater', '4   Seater', or 'Historic'.")
# No validation included for the input

FlightLen=input("Would you like to book the '30' minutes flight or the '60'")
# No validation included for the input

if (FlightLen==30):
    MaxSlots=(600/FlightLen)

elif (FlightLen==60):
    MaxSlots=(600//FlightLen)

print (MaxSlots)
```

When I run the code, why does the following error message appear?

> NameError: name 'MaxSlots' is not defined

Comment: If neither of those conditions are met `MaxSlots` will not be defined

Comment: `input` returns a string, but a string will never be `==` to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` is always returned as a string and thus never equal to an integer.

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline)

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Your `if` or `elif` is never true since an integer is not a string in the Python world (if you used an `else` it would always return that) so you never define the new variable (since it is never run).  What you need to do is to convert each `input()` to an integer.  This can be done using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
FlightLen=int(input("Would you like to book the '30' minutes flight or the '60'"))
```

Here `FlightLen` has been converted to an integer once an input value has been given.

---

You do not need the `()` in the `if` `elif` statements if you are using Python 3 either:

```
if FlightLen==30:
elif FlightLen==60:
```

If you are using Python 2 `print` does not take an `()`

---

You might also want to add an `else` to make sure `FlightLen` is always defined, ensuring you do not get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int` function to convert it to integer and initialize MaxSlots variable with a value.

```
FlightType=int(input("Which flight would you like to fly? Type '2 Seater', '4   Seater', or 'Historic'."))

FlightLen=int(input("Would you like to book the '30' minutes flight or the '60'"))

MaxSlots = 0

if (FlightLen==30):
    MaxSlots=(600/FlightLen)

elif (FlightLen==60):
    MaxSlots=(600//FlightLen)

print (MaxSlots)
```