# python 3.6 and tdl "console is not defined error"

Tags: python-3.6

I'm trying to make a roguelike with python 3 and tdl, but when I try to run

it there's a 'console not defined' error (see image below) I tried to do things like import console or import win32console as console. But it shows the same error

This is the code I'm using:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable not defined (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048874/variable-not-defined-python)

Comment: Well the problem is... You don't define `console`. Python doesn't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, console appears to be a part of the tdl package, so you should try replacing `console.draw_char` with `tdl.console.draw_char` or add `from tdl import console` as one of your import statments.